# Create a variable for each array item

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code for my post sign up page on my site.

```
$email = $request['email'];
$username = $request['username'];
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);
$mmail = $request['mmail'];
$terms = $request['terms'];

$user = new User();

$user->email = $email;
$user->username = $username;
$user->password = $password;
$user->mmail = $mmail;
$user->terms = $terms;

$user->save();
```

I need to know if it is possible to simplify my code incase I add new sign up options. What I'm trying to do is create a variable for each item in the `$request` array which can then be used by the `$user->sqltable = $sqltableitem`

Something like

```
foreach ($REQUESTITEM?? as $???){
   ???
}
```

Is this possible and any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a variable for each element. Just use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

One this clause does exactly the same as all your posted code.

Don't forget to fill `$fillable` array:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'mmail', 'terms'];
}
```

If you want to `bcrypt` password manually, the right way to do this will be [creating mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function set setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also bcyrpt my passwords?

Comment: @Albert, I don't know which auth system do you use, but if you need to do that manually, use mutators (check the updated answer).

Comment: I did this before the clause and it works perfectly `$request['password'] = bcrypt($request['password']` , No need for that other bit. I've edited the question so can you accept it

Comment: @Albert, thanks for suggestion, but the right way to do that kind of stuff is to use mutators. You controllers should be tiny and Model related logic should be in a Model.

Comment: You're right, I'll try have a shot with the mutators